# How to add custom extension(time) to <message> tag?

Tags: android, time, xmpp, message

I'm trying to add time extension to message with custom packet extension. It seems like time gets added while sending message. But at receiver end, it shows null.

This is my packet extension class and EmbeddedExtensionProvider

```
public class TimestampExtension implements PacketExtension {

    public static final String ELEMENT = "timestamp";
    public static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:xmpp:timestamp";

    public String TIME = null;

    public TimestampExtension() {

    }

    public void setTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        Date dateTime = new Date();
        String strTime = time.format(dateTime);
        this.TIME = strTime;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return TIME;
    }

    @Override
    public String getElementName() {
        return ELEMENT;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespace() {
        return NAMESPACE;
    }

    @Override
    public String toXML() {
        return "<" + ELEMENT + " xmlns='" + NAMESPACE + "'><time>" + TIME
            + "</time></" + ELEMENT + ">";
    }

    public static class Provider extends EmbeddedExtensionProvider {

        @Override
        protected PacketExtension createReturnExtension(String arg0,
            String arg1, Map<String, String> arg2,
            List<? extends PacketExtension> arg3) {

            return new TimestampExtension();
        }
    }
}
```

Registering provider

```
ProviderManager.getInstance().addExtensionProvider(
            TimestampExtension.ELEMENT, TimestampExtension.NAMESPACE,
            new TimestampExtension.Provider());
```

Sending message with extension

```
TimestampExtension timeExt = new TimestampExtension();
timeExt.setTime();
msg.addExtension(timeExt);
connection.sendPacket(msg);
```

Message xml output at sender:

```
<message id="m55K5-7" to="testfirzan@sushant" type="chat">
<body>hi</body><request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/>
<timestamp xmlns='urn:xmpp:timestamp'>
<time>01:04 PM</time>
</timestamp>
```

Message xml output at receiver:

```
<message id="m55K5-7" to="testfirzan@sushant" from="testsushant@sushant/Smack" type="chat">
<body>hi</body><request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/>
<timestamp xmlns='urn:xmpp:timestamp'>
<time>null</time>
</timestamp>
```

It's supposed to show sending time in time element. What i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry folks for late answer.

Since time was mandatory parameter for me, i end up using `DefaultPacketExtension`

```
//To sent message
private void sendMessage(String message, String recipient) {

    Message msg = new Message(recipient, Message.Type.chat);
    msg.setBody(message);

    //Getting current timestamp in string format
    String messageTimeStamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

    //Creating default packet extension with name as 'timestamp' and urn as 'urn:xmpp:timestamp'
    DefaultPacketExtension extTimeStamp = new DefaultPacketExtension(
                                        "timestamp", "urn:xmpp:timestamp");

    //Setting value in extension
    extTimeStamp.setValue("timestamp", messageTimestamp);

    //Add extension to message tag
    msg.addExtension(extTimeStamp);

    //Send message
    xmppConnection.sendPacket(message);
}


//To receive and parse message with extension implement PacketListener
@Override
public void processPacket(Packet packet) {

    Message message = (Message) packet;

    //Get the extension from message
    DefaultPacketExtension extTimestamp = (DefaultPacketExtension) message
                    .getExtension("urn:xmpp:timestamp");

    //Get the value from extension
    long timestamp = Long.parseLong(extTimestamp.getValue("timestamp"));

    System.out.println("Message :" + message.getBody() + " Timestamp: "+timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Sushant's answer is correct but with latest version of `org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.2.0-beta2` they have changed the `DefaultPacketExtension`  to `StandardExtensionElement` for adding custom element in message.

Code to add extension

```
//Creating Standard packet extension with name as 'timestamp' and urn as 'urn:xmpp:timestamp'
 StandardExtensionElement extTimeStamp = StandardExtensionElement.builder(
        "timestamp", "urn:xmpp:timestamp")
        .addAttribute("timestamp", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))  //Setting value in extension
        .build();


//Add extension to message tag
message.addExtension(extTimeStamp);
```

Hope this will help future developers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Provider

```
        return new TimestampExtension();
```

you need to get time element from the XmlPullParser when parsed the message and set it to your extension instance.

Comment: I haven' parsed message yet because required time element is null. I think server is dropping value in `time` element.